# Web-scraped data only works sometimes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape stock earnings data from a website. Outside of market hours, the code works. During market hours the code will say "list index out of range" most of the time. I realize this is because the website's html code above the piece of data I want changes or drops out to load something else, but is there anything to do about this? Or am I just at the mercy of what the website is doing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
stocks = ['AAPL']
for stock in stocks:
    url = f'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/{stock}/analystestimates?mod=mw_quote_tab'
    res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    thisyear = soup.findAll('th', class_ = "table__cell")[8].text
    print(thisyear)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly at the mercy of the website. It would be preferable to find an API with the same/similar data if possible.

Without seeing the trace, the `IndexError` is likely from the `[8]`, or more specifically, from the `soup.findAll('th', class_ = "table__cell")` returning a list with fewer than 9 items.

You could assign `items = soup.findAll(..)` and check `if len(items) >= 9` before getting that value, and/or call a different scraping method. You can also wrap it in a try-catch block:

```
def main():
    for stock in stocks:
        try2scrape(stock)

def try2scrape(stock):
    try:
        return scrape_data(stock)
    except IndexError as e:
        return scrape_data_another_way(stock) # or just error
```